# uwamp drupal 8 install new module fails

Tags: php, ssl, curl, drupal, uwamp

I am getting

> Failed to fetch file due to error "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

error message when I try to install a module in Drupal 8.1.8

I found https://www.drupal.org/node/2654474#comment-11232057 which seems to say it is a problem with my stack, UwAMP. I did not follow the procedure in that post because it indicated it did not fix the problem.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution at https://www.drupal.org/node/2654474#comment-11553625

In my case I had to add a "certs" folder to C:\UwAmp\bin\apache\conf\ then download the cacert.pem to that certs folder. I also had to add "curl.cainfo = C:\UwAmp\bin\apache\conf\certs\cacert.pem" to my php.ini file using the UwAmp GUI.

For the benefit of those of us who are newbies please explain what's happening here and why the solution fixed the problem. Please also explain why there is not some kind of fix to Drupal 8 to prevent this problem from happening.

Thanks!